# multiple calls inside map and display using react-native-select-multiple

Tags: javascript, react-native, multi-select

I've an issue, Im trying to display a list of data using

```
SelectMultiple from "react-native-select-multiple"
```

Now, i've from previous screen, Im using  `this.props.navigation.navigate` and get an array with values

```
[{val:24, name:'India'},{val:23, name:'Iceland'}]
```

and store on top in an array as

```
mySelectedCountries = this.props.navigation.state.params.countries;
```

and then making use of select multiple and trying to display each countries state list with an API.

Here's my get request

```
getStates = (val) => {
        ajax.get(route('states.index'), {
            params: {
                country_id: val,
                all: true
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('States list', res.data.data);
            this.myStatesData.push(res.data.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({ loading: false }, () => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Something went wrong!',
                'Please go to previous step and retry',
                [],
                { cancelable: true },
            );
            });
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

and then Im trying to map on the statesData which was declared on top of my program as empty array

```
myListedData = this.myStatesData.map((oneState) => {
            return (<SelectMultiple
                            items={oneState.map((x) => ({ label: x.name, value:x.id }))}
                            selectedItems={this.state.selectedStates}
                            onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange}
                            maxSelect={3}
                        />)
        })
```

which Im displaying in the return as `{myListedData}`

all i want is country name followed by its list of states and so on. Please note that the above array which has name of country and id (mySelectedCountries), on each of the id , I need to make API call to the state so that i can get list of states that are inside this country id. Im doing so in the `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.mySelectedCountries.map((x) => {
            return this.getStates(x.value);
        })

    }
```

Please let me know if you need additional information on this, thankyou in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In `componentDidMount` function you have array of async functions.

You need to wait for all ajax request to be done then do `setState` to re render the component.

Here is my solution:

```
getStates = (val) => {
        ajax.get(route('states.index'), {
            params: {
                country_id: val,
                all: true
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.data.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({ loading: false }, () => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Something went wrong!',
                'Please go to previous step and retry',
                [],
                { cancelable: true },
            );
            });
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        Promise.all(
            this.mySelectedCountries.map((x) => {
                return this.getStates(x.value);
            })
        ).then(arrayOfAllGetStates => {
             this.setState({myStatesData:arrayOfAllGetStates})
        })

    }
```

Then you need to map over `this.state.myStatesData` in render function

Comment: I'll check it and let you know :)

Comment: I'm still getting map undefined, probably myStatesdata = [undefined, undefined] , so should i put a loader first and then try?